# Access average response times in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am looking for a way to assert that the average time taken for certain HTTP requests is below an upper limit value:

- I can add a duration assert to the HTTP request, but a spike in the duration for whatever reason would fail the assertion.
- I can also compute these averages manually, given that I can access the individual request times, but I was hoping there might be an easier way to do it.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

My way for this problem is to use short timeout (ms) for my HTTP request, in your case choose your limit as timeouts. Then every request with higher response time will count as error.